# Как Правильно вызвать метод или функцию с помощью события onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть обычная вот такая разметка. Текст в заголовке h1 должен заменяться по клику по нему. НО как можно заметить по открытию кода в браузере, заголовок меняется еще до клика по нему. Почему так?
Но при этом если присвоить событию text.onclick функцию change() сразу, то всё работает.. И я никак не могу понять почему?
  П.С если событие добавить прямо в атрибут к заголовку то опять же всё работает.
  П.П.С глубоко извиняюсь за такое плохое оформление вопроса, мой первый уж.

```html
<div>
    <!-- изменяемый заголовок  -->
    <h1 id="info">just a string</h1>
<script>
    var text = document.getElementById('info');
// функция для замены
function change() {
    text.innerHTML = 'the string was changed';
    return false;
};
text.onclick = change();
</script>
</div>

  <!-- Второй вариант при котором всё прекрасно работает  -->
<div>
    <!-- на этот раз заголовок с другим id чтобы ошибок не было -->
    <h1 id="info2">just a string</h1>
<script>
    var text = document.getElementById('info2');
// тут событие и функция связываются
text.onclick = function change() {
    text.innerHTML = 'the string was changed';
    return false;
};

</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в первом случае Вы сразу же вызываете функцию change(), поэтому текст меняется до клика. Чтобы этого не происходило, пишите change без скобок:

```html
<div>
    <!-- изменяемый заголовок  -->
    <h1 id="info">just a string</h1>
<script>
    var text = document.getElementById('info');
// функция для замены
function change() {
    text.innerHTML = 'the string was changed';
    return false;
};
text.onclick = change; //вот здесь не должно быть вызова функции
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: что если функция с параметрами?  что тогда?
`  
function change( arg ) {  
    arg.innerHTML = 'the string was changed';  
    return false;  
};  
text.onclick = change ;`

Comment: @ШахаСадинов, тогда используйте анонимную функцию, которая будет вызываться по клику и внутри которой уже будет вызов change:  text.onclick = function() { change(arg) }